# Looping ansible ec2 hostnames from input file/variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to assign to hostname to AWS EC2 instances from Ansible and It was provisioned from Terraform and Jenkins. I have extracted the hostname output from Terraform and stored as a *input.txt* file, I want to call the input.txt file to pass the hostname values.

I tried the below playbook but result is not expected.
The expected output should be

- `host1: test1`
- `host2: test2`

```
---
- hosts: main
  become: true
  
  tasks:
    - name: Configure hostname
      win_hostname:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      register: result
      with_items: "{{lookup( 'file', 'input.txt').split('\n') }}"
```

Which gives

```
TASK [Configure hostname] ****************************************************
changed: [13.57.245.193] => (item=test1)
changed: [54.193.219.112] => (item=test1)
changed: [13.57.245.193] => (item=test2)
changed: [54.193.219.112] => (item=test2)
```

*input.txt*:

```
test1
test2
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to loop in this scenario, targeting a group of hosts will actually make the **same task** happen on all hosts.
If you indeed add a loop to a task, the same task will repeat on all host times the number of items in the loop — i.e.: here, with two hosts and two items in the loop: `2x2=4`.

What you could do, although you should really consider using a more robust approach like tagging your EC2 in Terraform and then using the information from the tags in a [dynamic EC2 inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html), is to use the position of the host Ansible is currently targeting to match it to a position in your *input.txt* file.

This can be achieved with the help of the [`ansible_play_hosts_all` special variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html).

Given the task:

```yaml
- name: Configure hostname
  win_hostname:
    name: "{{ _hostnames[_position | int] }}"
  register: hostname_result
  vars:
    _hostnames: "{{ lookup('file', 'input.txt').split('\n') }}"
    _position: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all.index(inventory_hostname) }}"
```

You will get the hostname you expect assigned to your hosts.

Comment: β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks, This is what i am looking for and worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here seems to be that it runs from `2` hosts

```
---
- hosts: main
```

The `main` seems to have `13.57.245.193` and `54.193.219.112`. You should remove one of the from the inventory file

---

If this not an option, you could configuring the `main` hosts like following

```
[main]
test1 ansible_host=13.57.245.193
test2 ansible_host=54.193.219.112
```

And then you for the task

```
- name: Configure hostname
  win_hostname:
    name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
  register: result
```

Comment: Thanks @Tolis Gerodimos, when inventory_hostname != '13.57.245.193' is not a static one, whenever we provision a server it will create new IPs. How can we create a dynamic condition to a input.txt file in when?

Comment: In your examle the hostname test1, test2, should be applied to 13.57.245.193 and 54.193.219.112. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes you are  correct. What if the IP address change in When condition, Can we create a dynamic condition. Example each time provision we get a new ip address and that ip address will be used as a hostfile to run the playbook and we don't know what ip we will get to specify in when condition.

Comment: Can you provide a sample  of the configuration of  the"main" hosts/group

Comment: am using below shell command to append the IP address from terraform

`code`
 sh '''printf \\
                    "\\n$(terraform output -json instance_ips | jq -r \'.[]\')" \\
                    >> aws_hosts'''

`code`
[main]
x.x.x.x
y.y.y.y

The X and Y value is dynamic from printf after the provisioning the servers.

Comment: i believe the loop is causing the problem.

Comment: @sk4ever if you could alter the structure of your main hosts, the answer I propose now would be elegant.
But β.εηοιτ.βε's answer should do the trick also

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works without loop.

Comment: @sk4ever If the answer works, please aprove or/and upvote. In order to help future users to find the answer to the problem